# How to reset for loop to make it read a list from the beginning

Tags: python, loops

So I have a for loop, which deletes elements of the list if it meets some conditions. When it deletes the 2nd element, it continues for loop from 2nd element my problem is that I want it to start this loop from the beginning, so it checks a list from 1st item. Is it possible?

```
some_list = ["one", "two", "two", "one", "two", "three", "two"]

for element in some_list:
    if element == "one":
        if some_list.index(element) + 1 == two:
            some_list.remove(some_list.index(element) + 1)
```

here's some sample code. I want it to check there's "one", remove "two" and when it removes, start again at "one" in the beginning, remove "two", go to "one again, go to 2nd "one", remove "two" and list looks like this:

```
some_list = ["one", "one", "three", "two"]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing an iterator that you're actively looping over. It could produce some strange behavior. Is the end result to ONLY remove `"two"` if it's preceded by `"one"`, or do you just want to remove all `"two"`? If it's the latter, then this should do the trick: `[i for i in some_list if  i != "two"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is somewhat inefficient, as all the elements “two” are removed by the end of the loop, so it would be better to straight out remove all “two” elements.

```
for i, elem in enumerate(some_list):
    if elem == “two”:
        del some_list[i]
```

For the sake of answering the question, though, here is my solution:

```
i=0
while i != len(some_list):
    if some_list[i] == “one” and some_list[i+1] == “two”:
        del some_list[i+1]
    else:
         i += 1
```

Comment: But I want do delete "two" ONLY if it's next to the "one", this list was only an example which I should do better

Comment: Okay I updated my response so that the iterative does not increase if the element following the current element is “two”.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a while loop since the for loop in python once initiated follows along the initial execution unlike C++, Java, etc

```
some_list = ["one", "two", "two", "one", "two"]
i = 0
while( i != (len(some_list) - 1)):
    if some_list[i] == "one":
        if some_list[i + 1] == 'two':
            del some_list[i + 1]
            i = 0
            continue
    i = i + 1
print(some_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm to delete all 'two''s that occur after 'one':

```
>>> def del_two(some_list):
...     i = 0
...     while i < len(some_list):
...             if some_list[i] != 'one':
...                     i += 1
...                     continue
...             i += 1
...             while i < len(some_list) and some_list[i] == 'two':
...                     del some_list[i]

>>> some_list = ["one", "two", "two", "one", "two"]
>>> del_two(some_list)
>>> print(some_list)
['one', 'one']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try while loop instead of for loop and what you need will be this:

```
some_list = ["one", "two", "two", "one", "two"]

i = 0
while i < len(some_list):
    element = some_list[i]
    if element == "one":
        idx = i + 1
        if idx < len(some_list) and some_list[idx] == "two":
            some_list.pop(idx)
            i -= 1
    i += 1

print(some_list)
```